# Kaspersky Dangerous Object when installing QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, security

When I install QGIS 2.14 and 2.18, Kaspersky gives me a Dangerous Object message.  Below is a screen shot of the quarantine.

Is this something I need to worry about?

[image: Dangerous Object message]

Answer (score 13):

This - in my humble opinion - seems to be a "false positive". I uploaded it to virustotal.com and 0 of 56 scanners gave an error (last analyis ~ 2month ago). I forced virustotal to reanalyze the file and now one scanner from 56 scanners gave an alert : Kapersky.

You should send the file to Kapersky for analysis, so they can update their virus-definition file.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, these false alarms happen from time to time, for example

- [[Qgis-user] BitDefender detects Malware in QGIS 2.14](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2016-March/035643.html)
- [[Qgis-user] False positive with norton + whitelisting](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2016-December/038675.html)

As Kurt already mentioned correctly, it is best to inform the antivirus provider.